# How to merge rows with common identifier and sum the occurrences in new column?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
CustomerNumber | LogEntry
1                2016-02-03
1                2016-02-05
1                2016-02-07
2                2016-02-05
2                2016-02-07
```

And I want it summarized like this:

```
CustomerNumber | Frequency
1                3
2                2
```

I found a way of solving it, but it doesn't feel very elegant (I'm a novice).

```
customer_log <- active_sessions

unique <- unique(customer_log$customer_number)

session_starts = character()
customer_number = character()

for (i in 1:length(unique)) {
  session_starts[i] <- nrow(na.omit(customer_log[customer_log$customer_number == unique[i],]))
  customer_number[i] <- unique[i]
}

active_sessions = data.frame(session_starts, customer_number)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to better solve this? Many thanks.

Comment: `rle(customer_log$customer_number)` ?

Comment: @Tensibai That actually works great, but I need to sort my list by customer_number first.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using the `sqldf` package.

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT CustomerNumber, count(*) AS Frequency FROM df GROUP BY CustomerNumber")
```